# Is .sql file different for MySQL and SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlyog, mysql-error-1050

I have a .sql file and I want to load it into MySQL database. I don't know from which database (MySQL or MS-SQL) it was created.

Now, I am trying to import that file into MySQL database. It is showing errors while importing and executing that file.

> Q1. So, my question is whether the .sql file generated from MySQL and MS-SQL are different?

Note: I am using SQLYog software (graphical interface for MySQL) for importing the file.

**Here is the ERROR:**

> Query:
>   CREATE TABLE `ads` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>   `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `type` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `town` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `address` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `price` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `info` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `link` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `hasImage` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `language` varchar(2) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `time_added` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Error occured at:2009-09-08 17:41:01
Line no.:35
Error Code: 1050 - Table 'ads' already exists

> Query:
>   CREATE TABLE `ads` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>   `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `type` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `town` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `address` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `price` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `info` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `link` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `hasImage` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `language` varchar(2) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `time_added` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Error occured at:2009-09-08 17:41:21
Line no.:35
Error Code: 1050 - Table 'ads' already exists

> Query:
>   CREATE TABLE `ads` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>   `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `type` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `town` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `address` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `price` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `info` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `link` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `hasImage` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `language` varchar(2) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `time_added` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Error occured at:2009-09-08 17:41:35
Line no.:35
Error Code: 1050 - Table 'ads' already exists

> Query:
>   CREATE TABLE `ads` (
>   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>   `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `type` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `town` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `address` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `price` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `info` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `link` text collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `hasImage` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `language` varchar(2) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `time_added` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Error occured at:2009-09-08 17:42:07
Line no.:35
Error Code: 1050 - Table 'ads' already exists

> Query:
>   1   Stanford University 6700    http://www.orkut.co.in
>   .
>   .
>   .

Comment: Why not include the error messages in your question?

Comment: "MySQL and SQL": "SQL" as in "Microsoft SQL Server"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file extension ".sql" is essentially meaningless: it's just there so that *you* know what the file is. It will just be a plain text file containing SQL, which you can open in Notepad. Therefore, there's no special "mysql" or "sql server" extensions.

The errors you're getting there `"Table 'ads' already exists"` are because you're trying to create a table which already exists in the database. (Did you read the error?) You have a few options:

1. Change the SQL to this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ads ( id bigint(20) ...
   ```
2. Change the SQL to this:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ads;
   CREATE TABLE ads (id bigint(20) ...
   ```
3. Clear out all the tables in the DB first.

Comment: Still I had deleted the whole database and tried to re-load it again... but the same error occured

Comment: @Yatendra - have another look. Make sure that the right database is selected. Also check that the table isn't being created multiple times in your SQL script.

Comment: The script refers to InnoDB storage, which implies that it was written for MySQL. 

However the error clearly says that the ads table exists already. Probably seeing the whole script could reveal the problem.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server do, unfortunately, implement different dialects of SQL. So, the answer to your question :

> Q1. So, my question is whether the
>   .sql file generated from MySQL and
>   MS-SQL are different?

is "yes, quite possiby".  However, the specific error you're showing appears to be due strictly to a "Create table" statement on line 35 being executed over and over and over again, and that can't depend on such dialect differences, so the causes have to be other ones (such as bugs or subtle format differences in what that "SQLYog" program, which I'm not familiar with, expects as its input).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which software exported this file. Also check in the file's header which software did it and analyze the syntax to determine where this file belongs to. Note also that SQL is microsoft sql server.

Comment: @Sarfraz I had checked the header. The header is as follows:......-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.2.4
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: loc

Comment: @Goel: Then you should better use phpmyadmin to import this file and it will definitely work without errors. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  SQL varies greatly from database to database.  While there is a [SQL standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization) which most databases support much of, every database has numerous, incompatible nonstandard features and functions above and beyond that specified by the standard.

There are also many migration docs avaiable:

MSSQL => MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html

MySQL => MSSQL:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966396.aspx

There are two obvious things in your CREATE TABLE statement that MSSQL doesn't support which jump out immediately:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Those are both MySQL-specific statements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script is being executed multiple times (as the line number where the error occurs is the same each time). The error also indicates that you're trying to define a table that already exists, which may be from the first time this script ran. You may want to look into how the script is being run to see why it may be executing multiple times.

The SQL itself looks fine for MySQL. It wouldn't run with SQL Server.